# How to get the FlSpot touched in fl_charts

Tags: flutter, user-interface, fl-chart

I have a LineChart where the default behaviour is that a tooltip with the y value shows up when you touch the chart.

How would i be able to get the x and y values of the point touched on the chart to save it in a variable for example.

It has to be in this property of the LineChart:

```
lineTouchData: LineTouchData(enabled: true),
```

Answer (score 2):

you need more parameters in your `LineTouchData` property. The touch callback will send you a list of touched spots

```
LineTouchData(
          enabled: true,
          touchCallback: (event, response) {
            if (event is FlTapUpEvent) {
              if (response != null && response.lineBarSpots != null) {
                // print(event);
                // print(response);
              }
            }
          },
        ),
```